# java add items to JcomboBox from Database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

How can I add items to combobox from Access database?

My code:

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Owner,Cars "
        + "WHERE carID=CarID_ "
        + "ORDER BY OwnerName;";
    ResultSet dane = zadanie.executeQuery(sql);
    while (dane.next())
    {
        comboBox_2.addItem(new(dane.getString("year")));
    }
    zadanie.close();
} catch(SQLException sqe) {
    System.out.println("SQl error");
}
```

but it throws "Sql error"
btw this code:

```
    String sql="SELECT * FROM Cars ;";
    ResultSet dane = zadanie.executeQuery(sql);
    while (dane.next())
    {       

        System.out.println(
                dane.getString("CarName")+"\t" +
                dane.getString("year"));

    }
    zadanie.close();
} catch(SQLException sqe) {
    System.out.println("SQl error");
}
```

works perfectly but if write in that way it shows error

```
 comboBox_2.addItem(new String(dane.getString("CarName"))); 
        System.out.println(
                dane.getString("CarName")+"\t" +
                dane.getString("year"));
```

Comment: inserts only thirst item from database

Comment: Two things to aid you in the future. First - Learn how to handle exceptions to aid in debugging code. Within the `catch(SQLException sqe)` block place sqe.printStackTrace(System.out); to print a stack trace to the cause of the problem. This will print to terminal the specific problem encountered e.g. your SQL query being awful!

Second - Polish up your SQL skills!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a thread other than the `EDT`, it is essential to ensure that an event that modifies a Swing component is posted on the `EDT`. The utility class [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) allows you to do such.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        comboBox_2.addItem(new(dane.getString("year")));
    }
});
```

But this is not your current problem. Instead of printing out that useless message (i.e. *SQL error*), why not print a stack trace? Also, I suggest you read up on [`SQLException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html).

Answer (score 1):

You do have an error in your SQL at `WHERE carID = CarID_"` You are missing the actual ID of the Car. Hope this helps!

Comment: nopeproblem with adding itemin combobox, because using system.out.println shows me all data which i want as well as caID

Comment: Well, what I meant was the actual SQL statement has an error. In this case, your sql statement reads: `String sql="SELECT * FROM Owner,Cars WHERE carID=CarID_ ORDER BY OwnerName;"` Notice that the carID has no ID. I gather that it should read something like `String sql="SELECT * FROM Owner,Cars WHERE carID=CarID_5 ORDER BY OwnerName;"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a problem with your SQL... does that statement execute correctly outside of Java?

```
SELECT * FROM owner JOIN cars USING (carID) ORDER BY OwnerName;
```

May work out better for you?

Comment: doesn't work at all with this (also sql error)and doesn't insert no items.